# Dynamically create and append tab space in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to dynamically create a form and I need to append a Tab space between two elements. The only issue I guess with this is the tag(createElement(...)) that needs to be placed. Also please note that I have omitted many other elements that the form will be holding

```
function createStreamForm()
{
$(".toolbox-titlex").show();
$(".panel").show();

var Streamtype = document.createElement("div");
var br = document.createElement("br");
var streamlbl = document.createElement("label");
var streamtypelbl = document.createElement("label");
var PredefStreamdiv = document.createElement("div");
var tabspace = document.createElement("label");

Streamtype.type = "text";
Streamtype.id="Streamtype";
Streamtype.className = "streamType";
streamlbl.className = "lblstreamProp";
streamlbl.innerHTML = "Stream: ";
PredefStreamdiv.id = "PredefinedStream";
tabspace.innerHTML = "&nbsp";


lot.appendChild(Streamtype);
lot.appendChild(tabspace);
lot.appendChild(streamlbl);
lot.appendChild(streamtypelbl);
lot.appendChild(br);
lot.appendChild(PredefStreamdiv);

createattr();
$(".streamType").append(showStreamType());
$(".queryPanel").

hide();

}
```

Here I've tried using &nbsp in place of a tabspace but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try with `&nbsp;` (is an entity, and must be surrounded with & and ;). You can add a tab with `"\t"`, but probably the render don't show as you expected.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question, I've tried using &nbsp but it didn't work. So I had to switch to a table structure. But there should be a way of appending tab spaces and am curious 'bout that.

Comment: You have in your code `tabspace.innerHTML = "&nbsp";` (&nbsp), try with `tabspace.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";` (&nbsp;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with this solution `"&nbsp;"`
to create space between two dynamically created elements, you can also create any element for example span also which should not be block level element. For example to create space between checkbox and label which are created dynamically

```
var cb = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("label");
var span = document.createElement("span");
append(li,cb);
append(li,span);
append(li,label);
span.innerHTML = "  ";
```